# Не могу установить adb соединение по wifi с OPPO CPH1909

Tags: android, adb

У меня никак не выходит установить удаленное соединение по wifi через adb с OPPO CPH1909.

1. Подключаю телефон по usb, указываю tcpip 5555
2. Подключаюсь к нему по ip, adb connect 192.168.4.1 (тут ip смартфона в локальной сети wifi)
3. Пишет что соединение успешно установлено и через adb devices находит подключение по ip и по шнуру, но когда отключаю телефон от шнура, adb его не находит, пишет что список устройств пуст.

В то время как с другими смартфонами Samsung, Vivo, Honor... соединение устанавливается и держится успешно.

Возможно вы сталкивались с подобной проблемой?
(отладка по USB, само собой включена)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена, смартфон просто почему то при отключении от usb сбрасывал все подключения, но удаленно после этого можно было все равно к нему законнектится уже без шнурка, с помощью adb connect 192.168.1....